# What does "git log -1" do?

Tags: git

What does the `-1` in `git log -1` do?

I looked through the [git log documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) but could not find any supporting documentation about this argument with git 2.16.2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This returns the most recent commit on a branch.

You won't find `-1` in the documentation, but you will find "`-<number>`":

```
-<number>
-n <number>
--max-count=<number>
Limit the number of commits to output.
```

Comment: Do you have a special gift that allows you to post questions and answers to those questions within seconds from each other?

Comment: @PeterB Yes, insofar as it's the the "answer your own question" checkbox when you're posting a question.  No, insofar as it is not special to me.  Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) out for more details. From Jeff Atwood: "To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."

Comment: Ok thanks, never realized that option existed - not much of an asker myself :-)

Comment: @PeterB No problem :)